# designing an app with multiple pages with different app bar and a single drawer

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build an app in Flutter in which I have multiple pages, each with their specific actions in the app bar. I would like to add a Drawer to the app which contains a list of page names that take them to the respective pages. I learnt that both AppBar and Drawer widgets have to be part of a Scaffold widget. Currently, all my pages are basically StatefulWidgets with the build method returning a complete Scaffold widget. If I want to include a Drawer, I think I will have to add the drawer object in each of my page. Is there a better way/pattern to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of my Apps, I have something similar. My Drawer is in the app class which is called in the main. This app class calls the home classes. My app class is also Stateful.
Each home class has his own Appbar and Search function.
The Drawer is called only in the app class.
Tell me if this explanation is okay for you or if you need a sample code.

Comment: I eventually followed a similar pattern in my application, I realized that it's ok to have each page have it's own Scaffold with AppBar.

Answer (score 1):

Write the code for the drawer once and enclose it in a function. Then just call the function each time for that drawer.
eg)

```
drawer: myDrawer()
```